# Объявлена переменная или нет?

Tags: javascript

Как в javascript-е определить объявлена переменная или нет?

Например:

```
if(!tmp){
    var tmp=$("<div />");
    tmp.dialog();
}else{
    if(!tmp.dialog("isOpen")) tmp.dialog("open");
}
```

и надо чтоб tmp была глобальной, чтобы каждый раз не создавать диалоговое окно...

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы проверить, определена ли переменная, используйте сравнение typeof с "undefined"

```
if(typeof tmp !== "undefined"){
    // Определена
}
else{
    // Не определена
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы переменная была глобальной, объявите её без ключевого слова var.

Comment: Я все таки решил не глобализовать переменную.

Comment: И это правильно :)